# Flutter Firebase Cloud Firestore How to filter a stream with where() query using a subcollection

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

So i have in my Cloud Firestore I have a collection of recipes that contains documents(with casual ids) with different recipes. Every document has a 2 fields with the recipe name and the recipe duration.
Every document has also a collection named likedBy where there is documents that have as ids user ids and have a single field with the date of the like.
Now i want to return all recipes that have in their likedBy subCollection the userId.
i' ll write what i' ve tried with only essential code.

```
String userId= 'uiuu4fn3fff4fu';  

Scaffold(
body:StreamBuilder(
stream: THE STREAM THAT I NEED,
builder:(context,snapshot){
return ListView.builder(
itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length
itemBuilder:(context,index){
return Column(children:[
Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['recipeName']),
Text(snapshot.data.documents[index][recipeDuration]),]) } ) } ) )
```

What i want is to return only documents that have in their likedBy subCollection a specific user uid.

I' ve tried with this stream

```
Firestore.instance.collection('recipes').parent().collection('likedBy').where(FieldPath.documentId, 
isEqualTo,userId).snapshots()
```

But it doesn' t work and i have no idea what else i can try.
Any help is highly apprecieted.

Items should not be added by the users but by admins, that means that there will be a list of items added by admins and a list of users that can add them in favorites and what i want to achieve is that users can see all their favorites in the order in which they saved them. To be clear i want something like Instagram functionality to save posts.

Answer (score 1):

So you want a way to query subcollection. To do that simply use [collectionGroup method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query):

```
db.collectionGroup('likedBy').where('userId', '==', '1');
```

To order by a value use timestamp:

```
// add to your document
db.collection("items")
 .add({...item, created: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()) })
```

and to orderby this value use orderby:

```
db.collection("items")
     .orderBy("created", "asc")
```

Comment: In that way i can only return the data of the fields of likedBy sub collection but what i want to do is to return all the recipes that have in their subcollection likedBy a specific userId.

Comment: if this what you want then what @Kris said is your best solution. add a likedBy field which is an array of users that liked that recipe and query them with array-contains method. if you want to use array-contains again then you have to make another query

Comment: Thanks for the answer but again i want to show the recipes in the order in which they were saved using a TimeStamp and setting the data to DateTime.now() and order them by that field

Comment: you can use [orderBy](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) method

Comment: Which field i have to order them by?

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer but the item should not be added by the users but by admins, that means that there will be a list of items added by admins and a list of users that can add them in favorites and what i want  to achieve is that users can see all their favorites in the order in which they saved them. To be clear i want something like Instagram functionality to save posts. Again thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to do instead is have a 'likedBy' property on the recipe document instead of its own sub-collection. If it is just a list of userids that should be no problem. Then you can just say recipeCollection.where(likedBy, array contains: userId)

Comment: thanks for the answer but i was hoping to find another solution since i need the array contains to filter another field and Cloud firestore doesn't allow to put more than one array contains.

Comment: I was also hoping to find a solution that show the recipes in the favorite page in the order in which they were saved.